# Do I require loading in this example of load store architecture?

Tags: computer-architecture

I'm currently revising for my Concurrent Programming exam and I'm going through the past papers and one question poses the following process:

```
Process P1
 integer x;
1a: x = a + a;
1b: b = x;
end P1;
```

and asks the following question:

> Rewrite processes P1 to take into account execution using a ‘load/store’
>   architecture.

For `1a`  I have broken it down into this:

```
load a into R
add a to R
store R into x
```

Where `R` refers to the register as per my notes.

My trouble lies in `1b`. Do I need to `load x into R` before I `store R into b` or can I simply bypass the register and `store x into b`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to load x into R before you store R into b

wikipedia says:

In computer engineering a load/store architecture only allows memory to be accessed by load and store operations, and **all values for an operation need to be loaded from memory and be present in registers**. Following the operation, the result needs to be stored back to memory.

In your case, x is still in memory and has to be loaded into a register.